# How to rename all files and subfolders within a directory using Python

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a small project using a book about Python. One of the examples they show is how to rename all of the files and directories right underneath the root folder, however I want to go a step further and change files within sub directories.

I figured using `os.walk` would be my best bet but I can only get it to change file names not subdirectories. I would like to also change subdirectory names as I go through `os.walk`.

I am using a book and online resources to accomplish this, any help would be awesome.

Here is what I have right now based on the book. I have tried to include `os.listdir` but the regex won't work like that.

`import shutil, os, re

#regex that matches files with dates
wrongFormat = re.compile(r"""^(.*?)
    ((0|1)?\d).
    ((0|1|2|3)?\d).
    ((19|20)\d\d)
    (.*?)$
    """, re.VERBOSE)
#Loop over the files in the working directory
path = '.'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for incorrectDt in files:
        dt = wrongFormat.search(incorrectDt)
#Skip file without a date
        if dt == None:
            continue
#Split filename into parts
        beforePart = dt.group(1)
        monthPart = dt.group(2)
        dayPart = dt.group(4)
        yearPart = dt.group(6)
        afterPart = dt.group(8)

#Form the new date format
        correctFormat = beforePart + monthPart + "_" + dayPart + "_" + yearPart + afterPart

#Get full, absolute file paths.
        absWorkingDir = os.path.abspath(path)
        incorrectDt= os.path.join(absWorkingDir, incorrectDt)
        correctFormat = os.path.join(absWorkingDir, correctFormat)

#rename files 
        print ('Renaming "%s" to "%s"...' % (wrongFormat, correctFormat))

        shutil.move(incorrectDt, correctFormat)`

Comment: How do you want to change the subdirectories?
If you want you use the same regex then then just simple add the directories to your loop. E.g change:
for incorrectDt in files:
to
for incorrectDt in (files, dirs):

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dateFix.py", line 14, in <module>
    dt = wrongFormat.search(incorrectDt)
TypeError: expected string or buffer                                                        I tried but I keep getting this error (sorry I am new to stack)